# reader.onload = function () not getting executed

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert Binary File in Base64 Encoded string using FileReader.
Nothing gets executed inside once the reader.onload = function () is called.

I need to call docUpdate(paramObj) method inside reader.onload().

```
function getBase64(file, paramObj) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
    (paramObj['documentInfo']).binaryStr = reader.result;
    docUpdate(paramObj);
    alert("Hello");
  };
  reader.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  };
}
```

There is no console.log and Alert is also not executed.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried setting the event handlers *before* reading the file? Not sure if it'll make a difference, but worth a try.

Comment: Well, if you read the file then set the loader, not much to be done. The docs set the event handler before events will be fired as well. Not much else makes sense.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm pretty sure it must not make a difference - the event is always asynchronous.

Comment: "*Binary File in Base64 Encoded string*" - that's not what you should use `FileReader` for - its purpose is to read from Blob objects, not from strings. What exactly is the `file` that you are passing?

Comment: @DaveNewton The order shouldn't matter, since file reading is asynchronous. The event doesn't happen until after the function returns and all the event handlers have been assigned.

Comment: @Barmar Wouldn't that be an assumption? Or because the read and assign are in the same context it's guaranteed that the onload will be assigned before the next tick and we assume it's a large-enough file, and that nothing tricky happens with the onload assignment?

Comment: @DaveNewton Event handlers are run by the main event loop. Since JavaScript is single-threaded, the event loop doesn't run until all JS functions return.